# javafx-8: onDropOver is never called for external files

Tags: file, drag-and-drop, javafx-8, fxml

I'm working on my first JavaFX project.

*(I did some Swing before and usually C# front end and Java backend.)*

**Setup:**

The application contains a TableView which displays rows of UploadFile, a custom wrapper around java.io.File to display additional properties. The files are meant to be uploaded to a server eventually.

Now I want to add the option to drag files from the OS explorer and drop them on the table to be added if they have the right properties.
I also want to allow dragging files from the table to either a garbage area or just outside the table, which will remove the files from the table.

**Problem:**

When I drag a file from the table I get a call to `handleDragDetected(MouseEvent e)`.

However if I drag a file from the explorer into the table none of the event handlers get called. (I tried on Windows 10 Pro)

**Question:**

Do I need to switch this on somehow or what am I missing here?

**Code:**

Some of the FXML:

```
<VBox fx:id="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
    fx:controller="com.company.project.gui.controllers.FormController">
  <children>
    ..
    <TableView id="tbl-files" editable="true" 
        onDragDetected="#handleDragDetected" onDragOver="#handleDragOver"
        onDragEntered="#handleDragEntered" onDragExited="#handleDragExited"
        onDragDropped="#handleDragDropped" onDragDone="#handleDragDone">
      <columns> .. </columns>
    </TableView>
    ..
  </children>
</VBox>
```

... and the controller class:

```
package com.company.project.gui.controllers;

public class FormController {
  @FXML
  protected void handleDragDetected(final MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragDetected: " + e.toString());
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleDragOver(final DragEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragOver: " + e.toString());
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleDragEntered(final DragEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragEntered: " + e.toString());
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleDragExited(final DragEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragExited: " + e.toString());
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleDragDropped(final DragEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragDropped: " + e.toString());
  }

  @FXML
  protected void handleDragDone(final DragEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DragDone: " + e.toString());
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I also added handlers for the `onMouseDrag..` events and tried adding them in code instead of FXML. The result is still the same. I guess I focus on draging files out of the table for the moment since that seems to work.

**EDIT 2:**

I finally had some time to look into this a bit more.

I actually copied a complete minimal example (see below) and I get the same result. None! I even tried to put the listeners on the scene itself, but this did not work either. When I drag a file into the application windows, the cursor changes to indicate that is not allowed, while none of the listeners are ever being called. (My understanding is onDragOver should be called before rejecting the drag, since this is where the application would decide under which condition to accept the dragged content.)

I also run the program from command line, updated the JDK to 8u66 for 32 and 64 bit and tried again. I have no clue why it does not work.

```
package dragAndDropTest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragAndDropTest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
      Label label = new Label("Drag a file to me.");
      Label dropped = new Label("");
      VBox dragTarget = new VBox();
      dragTarget.getChildren().addAll(label,dropped);
      dragTarget.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("DragOver: " + event.toString());
              if (event.getGestureSource() != dragTarget
                      && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                  /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                  event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
              }
              event.consume();
          }
      });

      dragTarget.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

          @Override
          public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            System.out.println("DragDropped: " + event.toString());
              Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
              boolean success = false;
              if (db.hasString()) {
                  dropped.setText(db.getString());
                  success = true;
              }
              /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
               * transferred and used */
              event.setDropCompleted(success);

              event.consume();
          }
      });


      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.getChildren().add(dragTarget);

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);

      primaryStage.setTitle("Drag Test");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```

Comment: Your code should work as it is. Can you create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it?

Comment: Sorry been busy with other stuff, now added a complete example as you asked and it does not work for me.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I may have a solution

Comment: I have not looked at it for quite some time since other stuff was more important - as I remember it suddenly worked in a newer JDK-version so seemed like a bug in that particular version of JAVA (don't remember which version that was) - by all means post your answer

Comment: @LorenShqipognja What is your solution?